# import GPGGA data to google earth

Tags: gps, google

I have collected some GPGGA data in *.GPS file. Now how to import these GPGGA into Google Earth Pro.I want to see the result(lat, longt and height) in map.
The file is opened like that:
`$GPGGA,023302.00,3957.7942,N,11618.2941,E,1,09,1.1,78.52,M,-9.80,M,,*40
$GPGGA,023305.00,3957.7942,N,11618.2941,E,1,09,1.1,78.53,M,-9.80,M,,*46`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename the extension on your files to either `.log` or `.nmea`, [quote](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/%23!topic/earth/xo0BbFWiLcI):

> As of Google Earth release 5.2 (Free and pro versions) now supports
>   NMEA import (.log and .nmea files).

You can also try some [sites online](http://www.h-schmidt.net/NMEA/) that perform the [nmea2kml](http://pa-n.com/nmea2kml/) conversions.

This [www.gpsvisualizer.com](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth) site looks promising:

> 1. Click on the link above
> 2. Add your NMEA log file to "Upload your GPS data files here"
> 3. Click on "Create KML file"
> 4. Open the generated KML file in Google Earth
>
> Tip! Since GPS Visualizer has a 3MB file limit, it can be useful to
>   record your files using the NMEA Filter option. If you only record
>   $GPRMC sentences every 5 seconds, you will greatly reduce the file
>   size.

For a detailed explanation of KML and NMEA conversion [see here](http://www.toptechboy.com/arduino/lesson-25-display-your-gps-data-as-track-on-google-earth/).

Comment: http://www.h-schmidt.net/NMEA/     In this website, I don't know what meaning does modifying "Minimum distance" or "Minimum time" have? My data is collected by static single positioning. So the range among them is small. NOw I don't know whether modifying "Minimum distance" or "Minimum time" can influence the result.

Comment: @BryanYU I believe they influence the interpolation performed during the conversion. Did simply renaming your file extension not work?

Comment: You said I can change .txt to .kml directly?

Comment: Change .txt to either .log or .nmea

Comment: Then use google earth open .log or .nmea?

Comment: @BryanYU Yes, if that doesn't work then try the sites on my updated answer above.